# Text search without spaces

Tags: java, string, pattern-matching, full-text-search, matching

In a text file, with variable spaces among words, is there a significantly better way of searching for and matching a given sentence?

For example, if the text file contains the following phrase with the spacing (space and tab characters) as follows

```
Java   is a\t\tgreat     programming\tlanguage.
```

what would be the most efficient way of matching it, given the input words?

An obvious approach would be to strip (or ignore) spaces and match sequences of non-whitespace characters, which can be done with standard Java I/O and string manipulation features.

Answer (score 1):

Just using `\\s` (short for `[ \t\n\x0b\r\f]`) for matching any whitespace?

```
final String str="Java   is a\t\tgreat     programming\tlanguage.";
final String pattern = "Java\\s+is\\s+a\\s+great\\s+programming\\s+language.";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher match = pat.matcher(str);
if (match.find()) {
  System.out.println("Found");
}
```

Comment: Sure. That is the standard way, though. I was wondering if there is any cleverer way. Thanks.